# How to backtrace how main's called with gdb?

Tags: gdb, program-entry-point

Inside the `main`,is there any command to show how's it invoked?

Comment: Are you looking for a way of generating the backtrace inside `main()`, or do you just want to see the backtrace in the debugger?

Answer (score 4):

This might be what you're looking for, if I get the question right:

```
(gdb) help set backtrace past-main 
Set whether backtraces should continue past "main".
Normally the caller of "main" is not of interest, so GDB will terminate
the backtrace at "main".  Set this variable if you need to see the rest
of the stack trace.
```

so if you set it to `on` (and the debug info for the `libc` are available, cf. [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275693/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-perform-source-level-debugging-of-system-library-c/7566054#7566054)), you'll see a stack looking like that:

```
(gdb) where
#0  main () at ./functionPtr.c:8
#1  0x0000003c47e2139d in __libc_start_main (main=0x40052b <main>, argc=1, ubp_av=0x7fffffffde28, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>,     stack_end=0x7fffffffde18) at libc-start.c:226
#2  0x0000000000400449 in _start ()
```

with the surrounding [`libc-start.c`](http://216%09%20%20%20%20%20%20struct%20pthread%20*self%20=%20THREAD_SELF;217%09218%09%20%20%20%20%20%20/*%20Store%20old%20info.%20%20*/219%09%20%20%20%20%20%20unwind_buf.priv.data.prev%20=%20THREAD_GETMEM%20%28self,%20cleanup_jmp_buf%29;220%09%20%20%20%20%20%20unwind_buf.priv.data.cleanup%20=%20THREAD_GETMEM%20%28self,%20cleanup%29;221%09222%09%20%20%20%20%20%20/*%20Store%20the%20new%20cleanup%20handler%20info.%20%20*/223%09%20%20%20%20%20%20THREAD_SETMEM%20%28self,%20cleanup_jmp_buf,%20&unwind_buf%29;224%09%28gdb%29%20l225%09%20%20%20%20%20%20/*%20Run%20the%20program.%20%20*/226%09%20%20%20%20%20%20result%20=%20main%20%28argc,%20argv,%20__environ%20MAIN_AUXVEC_PARAM%29;) code looking like that:

```
struct pthread *self = THREAD_SELF;

/* Store old info.  */
unwind_buf.priv.data.prev = THREAD_GETMEM (self, cleanup_jmp_buf);
unwind_buf.priv.data.cleanup = THREAD_GETMEM (self, cleanup);

/* Store the new cleanup handler info.  */
THREAD_SETMEM (self, cleanup_jmp_buf, &unwind_buf);

/* Run the program.  */
result = main (argc, argv, __environ MAIN_AUXVEC_PARAM);
```