# What is the recommended way to perform source-level debugging of system library calls?

Tags: linux, glibc

I have a need to debug into some calls in system libraries, to understand how the calls differ, and why one or another would be failing.

It is now common for Linux distros to provide stripped system libraries and separate debug symbol files. For example, /lib/libc-2.8.so is stripped of symbols, leaving behind a section named .gnu_debuglink that contains info to find a separate debug file. The separate debug files are installable through a debug package, and contain symbolic info needed by gdb. It's well described here http://www.technovelty.org/code/debug-info-symbols.html and http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html

After installing the debug package and the sources, I was expecting that GDB would find the symbols and sources and I would be able to view listings and step into the calls. Instead, gdb tells me "no line number known for xyz"

I've verified that debug-file-location is correct, and directories is set to the source directories.

Is it even possible to do what I want?  Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: It's certainly possible as I've seen it done.  Have you also checked permissions, that the debug file can be read correctly by the debugger?  I would suggest that every time I've watched someone debug a standard library call looking for a problem, it has always turned out to be something that (in hindsight at least) was a kinda obvious problem with the call, that could actually be spotted inside the stack of the main application code :)

Comment: @asc99c - Agree with your assessment about bugs.  My motivation is to better understand what is happening under the covers. I find the glibc sources difficult to follow with the arch-specific implementations and macros, even more-so than the kernel syscalls.  I believe the most direct, deterministic method, then, would be to step into the code a bit to navigate an execution path or two.

Comment: As a follow-up, stupid problem: the .debug files in the debug package didn't actually contain any debug sections, hence gdb's inability to present source-level navigation.  I guess I'll get old-school and build from sources.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the `debug-file-directory` parameter in GDB? As per the documentation you pointed out, it should do what you want:

> `set debug-file-directory directories`
>       Set the directories which gdb searches for separate debugging
>   information files to directory. Multiple directory components can be
>   set concatenating them by a directory separator.
>
> `show debug-file-directory`
>       Show the directories gdb searches for separate debugging
>   information files.

For instance in my Fedora distribution, the directory is `/usr/lib/debug`.

You can also define it at compile time with

```
configure --with-separate-debug-dir=/usr/lib/debug ...
```